# Create rows of data conditionally

Tags: r, conditional-statements

A sample dataset:

```
Price=c(6651, 7255, 25465, 35645, 2556, 3665)
NumberPurchased=c(25, 30, 156, 250, 12, 16)
Type=c("A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B")
Source=c("GSC", "MYL", "TTC", "ZAF", "CAN", "HLT")
df1 <- data.frame(Price, NumberPurchased, Type, Source)
```

I want to be able to create a new dataframe with two additional variables (`ID`, `PurchaseDate`) but more rows of data based on variable `Type`.

The rules I want to apply:
If Type=A, `PurchaseDate` is "2013", "2014". 
If Type=B, `PurchaseDate` is "2013".
If Type=C, `PurchaseDate` is "2013", "2014", "2015".

If `Type` is A, divide `Price` and `NumberPurchased` by 2, and have 2 rows with different `PurchaseDate` as specified above.
If `Type` is B, leave as is with `PurhcaseDate` as 2013.
If `Type` is C, divide `Price` and `NumberPurchased` by 3, and have 3 rows with different `PurchaseDate` as specified above.

Therefore, I want something like this as a new dataset:

```
Price=c(3325.5, 3325.5, 3627.5, 3627.5, 8488.3, 8488.3, 8488.3, 11881.6, 11881.6, 11881.6, 2556, 3665)
NumberPurchased=c(12.5, 12.5, 15, 15, 52, 52, 52, 83.3, 83.3, 83.3, 12, 16)
Type=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C","B", "B")
Source=c("GSC", "GSC", "MYL", "MYL", "TTC","TTC", "TTC",  "ZAF", "ZAF","ZAF", "CAN", "HLT")
PurchaseDate=c("2013", "2014", "2013", "2014", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2013")
ID=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6)
df2 <- data.frame(Price, NumberPurchased, Type, Source, PurchaseDate, ID)
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. First, we will create an index for `Type`, then we will grow the data accordingly, then we will use the `data.table` package in order to compute the new variables.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, indx := as.numeric(factor(Type, levels = c("B", "A", "C")))]
# setDT(df1)[, indx := ifelse(Type == "C", 3, 2)] # Alternative index per your comment
df2 <- df1[rep(seq_len(.N), indx)]

df2[, `:=`(
            Price = Price/.N,
            PurchaseDate = 2013:(2013 + (.N - 1)),
            NumberPurchased = NumberPurchased/.N,
            ID = .GRP
           ), 
           by = .(Source, Type)][]

#         Price NumberPurchased Type Source indx PurchaseDate ID
#  1:  3325.500        12.50000    A    GSC    2         2013  1
#  2:  3325.500        12.50000    A    GSC    2         2014  1
#  3:  3627.500        15.00000    A    MYL    2         2013  2
#  4:  3627.500        15.00000    A    MYL    2         2014  2
#  5:  8488.333        52.00000    C    TTC    3         2013  3
#  6:  8488.333        52.00000    C    TTC    3         2014  3
#  7:  8488.333        52.00000    C    TTC    3         2015  3
#  8: 11881.667        83.33333    C    ZAF    3         2013  4
#  9: 11881.667        83.33333    C    ZAF    3         2014  4
# 10: 11881.667        83.33333    C    ZAF    3         2015  4
# 11:  2556.000        12.00000    B    CAN    1         2013  5
# 12:  3665.000        16.00000    B    HLT    1         2013  6
```

Comment: This solution works but a follow-up question -- would this work if Type=A, divide by 2, if Type=B, divide by 2 as well, and Type= C, divide by 3?

Comment: Yes, just change the first line to `setDT(df1)[, indx := ifelse(Type == "C", 3, 2)]` and then run the rest of the code as is. I've edited the answer so you can choose which index you want.